# Powerpoint macro to get the last modified date of a file

Tags: vba, macros, powerpoint

I want to get the last modified date of a ppt file and put the condition : if it's in after thursady of the week than out else go on. That's what i wrote but it doesn't work!

```
Sub proprietes()


Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FilePath = "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro Project\test v2"
Set f = fs.GetFile(FilePath)
fileModDate = f.DateLastModified
End Sub
```

i always get the mistake in `Set f = fs.GetFile(FilePath)`!!

Could you help me please? 
thanks a lot

Comment: Try adding File name with extension to the FilePath

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting?

Comment: I have tried adding the file type extension and it worked fine for me

Comment: it comes always Run-timr error '53'  File not found

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub proprietes()

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FilePath = "C:\Users\....\Desktop\TestPPT.pptx"
Set f = fs.GetFile(FilePath)
fileModDate = f.DateLastModified
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't understand what's wrong with it but it still doesn't work!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If im not wrong you are trying to find the time of a different PPT file(not the PPT in which you are running macro). Am i right? And it is in the 'Macro Project' folder

Comment: no no just for this one! but many users have access for it and can modifie it! so when someone modifies it, i want to see when does he did it

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
 FilePath = Dir("C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro Project\test v2*")
 fileModDate = FileDateTime(FilePath)
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php

Comment: Its not strange if you are not using the full path. For example `"C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro Project\test v2.ppt"`

Comment: i'm trying and nevr get it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
i want to get the last modified date of the running PPT in which i'm whriting my macro